# Page numbers in Editable RTF Export with Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, pagination, crystal-reports-2008

I've got a report which was created using Crystal Reports.
In the page footer section there's a formula, which displays the page number "Page X of Y".

If I export this reports as editable RTF and open it in Word (2010, v14.0.5128.5000, 64bit) the footer contains only the text from the first page on every page "Page 1 of 7".
If the report is exported as PDF however, the pagination is correct everywhere.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue still exists in the newest version of Crystal Reports and it seems as no one at CR does want to fix it.
I had to use a Word-Macro to change the page numbers to their correct values after the export.